# Private key stored in the TPM (Windows 11 Pro) for EAP-TLS

Tags: windows, authentication, tls1.2, x509, tpm

I am encountering "Access Denied" error during EAP-TLS authentication with Windows supplicant. Please note, that the private key of the client certificate is stored in the TPM (Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider).

I assume that the user doesn't have permission to access the private key stored in the TPM during TLS handshake process.

[image: Wireshark packet capture of the TLS handshake:]

Following is the certificate request details. I have included the "Client Authentication" key usage during certificate signing.

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=cnvalue"
Keylength = 2048 
Exportable = FALSE
UserProtected = TRUE
MachineKeySet = FALSE
ProviderName = "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider"
ProviderType = 1
RequestType = PKCS10
FriendlyName = "eap-tls test"
[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.32
```

I have tried enabling group policies related to credentials delegation but it didn't help.
[image: credentials delegation]

I would really appreciate any help with the configurations/steps that I am missing to make this work. Thank you!